# What was the flight path of China's hypersonic missile that circumnavigated sometime in summer 2021?

Tags: china, weapon, supersonic

I read on [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2021/11/17/politics/john-hyten-china-hypersonic-weapons-test/index.html):

> China's [test of a hypersonic missile](https://www.cnn.com/2021/10/22/politics/china-hypersonic-missile-joe-biden-nuclear-policy/index.html) over the summer [2021] "went around the world," the second most senior US general said in an interview released Tuesday, shedding new details on the test and warning that China might one day be able to launch a surprise nuclear attack on the United States.

What was the flight path of this missile? I'm especially curious to know the speed and height.

Answer (score 3):

The Chinese missile/glider was in LEO for some of its path, then re-entered the atmosphere as a glider.
There is a good article in the Economist: https://www.economist.com/china/2021/10/23/chinas-test-of-a-hypersonic-missile-worries-america

[image]

The speed while in the orbital phase of its flight would be similar to LEO satellites: about 7.8 Km/sec.

Its altitude could be lower than a stable LEO. Since it doesn’t complete a single full orbit, it can tolerate thicker portions of the thermosphere. 200 km would be a reasonable guess.

Comment: cue Supertramp's [Take The Long Way Home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmJaCaxC5DQ)